# Conditional Expectation of $W_t^3$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, stochastic-analysis

I am trying to prove that $E(W_t^3|\mathcal{F}_s) = W_s^3 + 3(t-s)W_s$ where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion and $\mathcal{F}_s$ is the usually filtration. So far, I am able to figure out most of the steps, but then I get stuck. Below is my attempt.

My attempt:

Observe that $W_t^3 = (W_s + W_t-W_s)^3$. Then
\begin{align}
E((W_s + W_t-W_s)^3 | \mathcal{F}_s) &= E(W_s^3 + 3W_s^2(W_t-W_s)+3W_s(W_t-W_s)^2+(W_t-W_s)^3|\mathcal{F}_s)\\
&= W_s^3 + 3W_s^2E(W_t-W_s |\mathcal{F}_s)+ 3W_sE((W_t-W_s)^2|\mathcal{F}_s) + E((W_t-W_s)^3|\mathcal{F}_s)\\
&= W_s^3 + 0\ + 3W_s(t-s)+E((W_t-W_s)^3|\mathcal{F}_s)\\
&=W_s^3 + 3W_s(t-s)+E((W_t-W_s)^3|\mathcal{F}_s).
\end{align}

This is the point where I get stuck. I do not understand how to show that $E((W_t-W_s)^3|\mathcal{F}_s) = 0$.

Comment: What do you know about the odd moments of normal rvs of mean zero?

Comment: I do not know much about moments beyond the first and second moment.

Answer (score 1):

For $t>s$, $W_t-W_s$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$. Hence, $E((W_t-W_s)^{3}|\mathcal F_s)=E((W_t-W_s)^{3}$. Since $(W_t-W_s)^{3}$ has a symmetric distribution, its expectation is $0$.

[All odd moments of $N(0,\sigma^{2})$ are $0$].

Comment: Why is it true that all odd moments are 0 for a normally distribute rv with mean 0?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{n} f(x)dx=0$ for $n$ odd if $f$ is an even function. This is because the integral of any odd function over the real line is $0$. The density $f$ of $N(0,\sigma^{2})$ is, of course, an even function. @chris7347

Comment: @geetha290krm ... as long as $x^nf(x)$ is integrable.  I'm not convinced OP even knows that.

Comment: Normal distribution has finite moments of all orders. @chris7347